# Check thread status in Parallel.foreach to exit when Onstop() is called

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services, parallel.foreach

I have an windows service which performs certain operation in parallel foreach. I don't want the parallel foreach to stop abruptly when onStop() method is called instead it has wait until all the threads in parallel foreach completes its operation and then service must stop. Not Sure on how to do this. Please find my sample code which I have below: Thanks in advance..

```
//Initialize the timer
Timer timer = new Timer();

public ScheduledService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    //handle Elapsed event
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
    timer.Interval = 60000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    timer.Enabled = false;    
    // wait till parallel foreach in processItem completes and then the stop

}

private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ProcessItems();
}

private void ProcessItems()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), drow =>
    {
      //...
      // Do Stuff
      //...
    });
}
```

Comment: Your basic problem might be the Timer rather than the ForEach(). I'm not completely sure on which thread this executes now. You can check `Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground` befor the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is set a flag (if required) when OnStop() is called and then write the code to stop the service after the parallel loop statement.